# What is kept when starting a New Game Plus playthrough?

Tags: the-darkness-2

When starting a New Game+, what do I keep and what is reset when starting over?

Can I change the difficulty for the second playthrough?

Comment: @RavenDreamer probably should have mentioned it, but I did watch a Q&A session with the devs and I know for a fact that there is a New Game+ mode.

Comment: @RavenDreamer http://www.shacknews.com/article/70536/darkness-ii-adding-new-game-plus-mode

Comment: Question reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this message when starting NG+:

[image: New Game+ allows you to start any chapter while retaining all the Relics, Talents, and Essence from your last playthrough. However, your current savegame will be deleted; are you sure you want to continue?]

> New Game+ allows you to start any chapter while **retaining all the Relics, Talents, and Essence** from your last playthrough. However, your current savegame will be deleted; are you sure you want to continue?

You can change the difficulty for this new playthrough.