# Will I get the Relic Hunter achievement completing the collection in New Game+?

Tags: the-darkness-2

I missed a few relics in my first playthrough, will I get the Relic Hunter Achievement if I collect them in New Game+? Or do I have to get them all in one playthrough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get them in a New Game Plus, as [you do not lose your Relics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49884/what-is-kept-when-starting-a-new-game-plus-playthrough) when starting one.

I can also personally attest to this because I've done just that; I missed 2 Relics on my first playthrough.